# count the number of div's in each container with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how I can count the number of div's inside the "bar" container then add the number as a class. For example in the first item class="bar 3" and the second class="bar 2"

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="bar">
     <div class="slide"></div>
     <div class="slide"></div>
     <div class="slide"></div>
  </div>
</div><!-- /item -->

<div class="item">
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="bar">
     <div class="slide"></div>
     <div class="slide"></div>
  </div>
</div><!-- /item -->
```

Comment: Just a note - if you're planning on using the number in the class to style the container it won't work.  CSS class names can't be (or start with) numbers.

Comment: That I am aware of. This is just simplified code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#item').each(function(i, elem){
    var $this = $(this),
        len = $(this).find('.bar').children('div').length;

    $this.addClass('bar ' + len);
});
```

While writting this I realized that you are using multiple `IDs` with the name `item`. That is no valid `HTML markup` and jQuery probably will only return the first occurence. Replace the ID with classes and use `$('.item')`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each($(".item"), function(i, d) {
    var count = $(d).find(".bar div").length;
    $(d).addClass("bar_" + count);
})
```

Comment: no `.count()` in jQuery. Use either `.size()` or directly `.length` property.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery 1.4 you can use a function as `.addClass()` argument:

```
$('.bar').addClass(function() {
    return $(this).children('div').length;
});
```